# How to give image url to Pinit button?

Tags: javascript, api, pinterest

I am trying to add the Pinit button to my website. The problem is that, the Pinit button requires the image url, but in my case the images are generated dynamically. So how do I add the Pinit button such that it Pins the the visible image of the page.

Something like this [example](https://www.addthis.com/get/sharing#.UP1JyWcrjBM) will do great.

Comment: Provide the code for the Pinit button - (I know I could go and look for it but future visitors aren't going to want to)

Comment: do you mind jQuery or do you want plain javascript, BTW i don't mind scripting either .....

Comment: @Yusaf: plain javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### http://jsfiddle.net/t4KHR/

run the below code once you have dynamically appended the images
set the parent variable as the ID parent of the images you want sharing

```
var url = document.location.href;
var parent = document.getElementById("imgholder");
var img = parent.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
    var newpin = document.createElement("a");
    newpin.href = 'http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=' + encodeURIComponent(url) + '&media=' + encodeURIComponent(img[i].src);
    newpin.className = "pin-it-button";
    img[i].parentNode.insertBefore(newpin, img[i].nextSibling)
    if (i == img.length - 1) {
        var s = document.createElement("script");
        s.type = "text/javascript";
        s.src = "//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js";
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(s);
    }

}
```

Comment: yes, it works this way too. But I will use my code as it's much less scripting. Anyways thanks for your answer. I may find it useful for some different case.And also I learned something new from this answer. Thank You very much.

Comment: that's ok, and just let me know what it is you need i'll do my best to help

Comment: Thanks Yusaf. I solved my problem. I will definitely seek help of your scripting skills if I need it.Thanks

Comment: Check the update it's a lot fancier http://jsfiddle.net/t4KHR/1/ and the images are also appended dynamically as you wanted

Comment: How can I place the pinit button outside the parent div, using your first script?

Comment: unless I use jquery i really can't say i have only wrapped everything in the `<div id="imgholder"></div>` because using plain javascript to append an element after the img it has to have a parent

Comment: what if I use Parent of imageholder div ?

Comment: that should work yes for only that individual parent, if you don't mind me asking is there more than one parent for the images?

Comment: actually, I want the pinit button to be free from the image. So that I can place it with other Social-sharing buttons.

Comment: in the first script the button is free from the image furthermore if you want to add more share buttons the second script will actually work better as it stops you having to fuss arround with appending buttons after the img

Comment: Can you show a similar example using jquery, where the pinit button is completely separate from the parent div. It will be very helpful.

Comment: do you want the images to be appended or already in the html?

Comment: I just need to place the Pinit button in a separate DIV. Not in the images parent DIV. It can be present in the HTML, that's no problem.

Comment: could you please create a fiddle like ----> http://jsfiddle.net/2RmYp/  , so i can see the structure of the html output you want pelase

Comment: the last jsfiddle can't fetch the image.

Comment: i'm currently in school, the computers are terrible but give http://jsfiddle.net/t4KHR/7/ a whirl if not i'll sort it when i get home

Comment: it works fine in the fiddle, I didn't apply it in the website but sure will work there too :)   ... thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
<a class="pin-it-button" href="javascript:void((function()%7Bvar%20e=document.createElement('script');e.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');e.setAttribute('charset','UTF-8');e.setAttribute('src','http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?r='+Math.random()*99999999);document.body.appendChild(e)%7D)());">

<img border="0" src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" title="Pin It" />

</a>
```

The code snippet given above solved my problem. What it does is rather than hardcoding the URL's to the code links, it uses javascript to fetch the current url and shows the images of the current pages to be Pinned.
And don't forget to include the following script in your header or footer

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```